# Reading an online based pdf files in python and separating data in to columns -OSError

Tags: python

I m having an issue with python in getting an online based pdf file to python. The below is the code i wrote

```
import PyPDF2
import pandas as pd
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
reader = PdfReader(r"http://www.meteo.gov.lk/images/mergepdf/20221004MERGED.pdf")
text = ""
for page in reader.pages:
    text += page.extract_text() + "\n"
```

nd this gives me an error

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'http://www.meteo.gov.lk/images/mergepdf/20221004MERGED.pdf'
```

If we fix this, how do we separate the extracted data in to separate columns using pandas?
there are three tables in this pdf file.I need the first one. I have tried so many tutorials but none of them helped me. Can anyone help me in this regard please?

Thanks,
Snyder

Comment: I was able to download the PDF and parse it, but PyPDF2 didn't seem to do a very good job. Would using something like [https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer/](PDFMiner) be an option?

Comment: @DraftyHat thanks for the comment. but the link is not working. I have tried lot of times but no solution found :(

Comment: @KJ thank youfor the comment. At least we can separate these in to 3 colmns like in the pdf file thatis okay. That one is also impossible ryt ?

Comment: Very sorry about markup fail. The link I meant to post is to PDFMiner: https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer/
I found it did a better job of parsing the page you linked.

Answer (score 0):

Part one of your question is how to access the PDF content for extraction.

In order to view modify or extract the contents the bitstream it needs to be saved as a editable file. Thats why a binary DTP / printout file needs download to view. Every character in your browser screen was downloaded as text then converted from local file byte storage into graphics.

The simplest method is

`curl -O  http://www.meteo.gov.lk/images/mergepdf/20221004MERGED.pdf`

which saves a working copy locally as `20221004MERGED.pdf`

The next issue is that multi language files are a devil to extract and that one has many errors that need editing before extraction.

Here we see in Acrobat or other viewers (on the left) there are failures where eastern characters are mixed in with western ones due to the language mixing, so need corrective edit as shown on the right. Also the underlying text for extraction as seen by pdf readers is western characters that get translated inside the PDF by glyph mapping but for the extractable searchable text are just garbled plain text. this is what Adobe sees for search that first line `` k`l²zìq&` m[&Sw`n `` so you can see the W 3rd character from right.

[image]

Seriously there are just so many subset related problems to address, that it is easiest to open the PDF in any editor to reset the fonts to what they should be in each language.
[image]

The fonts you need in Word Office etc. are Kandy as I used to correct that word plus these others :-

[image]